# Blocking Safari with Google Santa

Tags: macos, safari, google

I am trying to block the Safari web browser on our macOS devices. I am using Google Santa installed on user devices and pushing profile configurations via Intune in an attempt to block certain applications. I've had success blocking other applications, but not Safari.

I'm looking for help in determining how I can block Safari with Google Santa. I'm mostly confused regarding the exact path that Safari resides in and the proper way to format the path using the regex required for Santa.

Paths Used:

- `/Applications/Safari.App/`
- `/System/Cryptexes/App/System/Applications/Safari.app`
- `/System/Cryptexes/App/System/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari`

Regex:

- `^\/Applications\/Safari\.app\/.*$`
- `^\/System\/Cryptexes\/App\/System\/Applications\/Safari\.app\/.*`

The profiles are successfully applied, but Safari remains unblocked. FYI I am not using a server with Google Santa, just simply applying profile configurations to end-use devices. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: you could uninstall safari

Comment: @ruskes Safari can't be deleted...

Comment: @Ezekiel not correct, it can be done but with consequences

Comment: @Ruskes Why not posting this as an answer, including the steps required to remove Safari in Ventura or Sonoma?

Comment: To update I've been able to block Safari not by using regex, but by defining the path directly:

**santactl rule --block --path /Applications/Safari.app**


I've also been able to block via sha256 certificate.

**santactl rule --block -identifier**